# PHP Fatal Error

Tags: taxonomy-terms, installation

I'm getting a PHP fatal error whenever I try to use taxonomy_term_save(). I am using it in an install script which may be pertinent information.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /var/www/proface.com/includes/common.inc on line 7779, referer: http://domain/install.php?profile=company_install_profile&locale=en&op=start&id=1
```

Why would this happen? The terms look correct to me:

```
  $terms = array();

  drupal_load('module', 'taxonomy');
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('distributor_types');

  $term = new stdClass();
  $term->name = "Platinum Distributors";
  $term->description = '';
  $term->vid = $vocabulary->vid;
  $term->weight = 0;
  $term->vocabulary_machine_name = 'distributor_types';
  $term->format = 'plain_text';
  $term->uuid = 'ee4e4f18-ad5e-46df-a2e7-145876efd907';
  $terms[] = $term;
```

Pulled out each of the terms from a foreach loop and...

```
  taxonomy_term_save($term);
```

And when I print out the entity name that is causing problems, it spits out, "taxonomy_vocabulary".

This is the function throwing the error, the line with "new $class($entity_type)" is line 7779.

```
function entity_get_controller($entity_type) {
  $controllers = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  if (!isset($controllers[$entity_type])) {
    $type_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
    $class = $type_info['controller class'];
    $controllers[$entity_type] = new $class($entity_type);
  }
  return $controllers[$entity_type];
}
```

I believe the version for this is 7.22.

Comment: Without any more context it's hard to be helpful... What exact version of Drupal are you using?  On 7.25, line 7779 in common.inc points to the docblock for entity_load().  Also, it looks like you're creating default content in a custom install profile, at what point of the installation are you doing this?

Comment: I am attempting to create default content in a custom install profile. During the "installing Drupal" section, where it loads all of the default modules for the installation profile. The module throwing the error is installed during installation.

Comment: Can you upgrade to recent 7.x on dev copy and test if it wasn't already fixed? Your code looks pretty OK, at least at first glance

Comment: This appears to be the problem area: drupal_load('module', 'taxonomy');
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('distributor_types');

When these two lines are not commented out, that error is thrown.

Comment: What makes you think that upgrading would fix this? Upgrading would be very difficult on the current setup.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually my coworker that should get credit for this, not me, but here's the solution:

```
drupal_load('module', 'taxonomy');

module_enable(array('taxonomy'), FALSE);

$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('distributor_types');
```

The taxonomy module wasn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My working theory right now is that as of that point in your code Drupal isn't aware of the `taxonomy_vocabulary` controller. You could try running `entity_get_info('taxonomy_vocabulary')` first to inform Drupal of the `taxonomy_vocabulary` controller.

Comment: Would I run that after drupal_load('module', 'taxonomy');, or before?

Comment: Doesn't matter, tried both, neither worked.